# Header should display section if no subsection available

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I'm writing a document which uses `scrartcl` alongside with `twoside` and want to create a header with `scrpage2`. As expected the package prints the section on even pages and the subsection on odd pages. So far so good. But when there is no subsection available on an odd page (because the section doesn't have one or it comes later in the document) then the header is left blank.

Is it possible to display the section instead if no subsection is currently available?

An example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,komastyle]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

    \section{Section}

    \newpage
    \null
    \newpage

    \subsection{Sub-section}

    \newpage

    \subsection{Sub-section}

\end{document}
```

The header for pages 2-4 is fine and as expected but because on page 1 there is no subsection the header is left blank. I would like to print the section instead (as on page 2).

Edit: I tried to adapt the solution of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99219/komascript-scrpage2-odd-page-header-in-passages-without-a-section-two-sided-d?rq=1) (which is for `scrreprt`) to `scrartcl` but I still get the blank headers. I tried:

```
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markboth
    {\MakeMarkcase{\sectionmarkformat#1}}
    {\MakeMarkcase{\sectionmarkformat#1}}}
```

Edit2: It works with the above `renewcommand` but it has to appear after the include of the `scrpage2` package. Which makes kinda sense as the `sectionmark` command might also be renewed in there.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the package `scrpage2` is deprecated. The successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`. Then you can simple use a starred version of `\automark` to get the desired result:

```
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\blindtext[5]
\subsection{Sub-section}
\blindtext[5]
\subsection{Sub-section}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99219/komascript-scrpage2-odd-page-header-in-passages-without-a-section-two-sided-d?rq=1) solves also the problem if adapted accordingly:

```
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,komastyle]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{%
  \markboth
    {\MakeMarkcase{\sectionmarkformat#1}}
    {\MakeMarkcase{\sectionmarkformat#1}}}
```

Here it is important that the `\renewcommand` appears after `\usepackage{scrpage2}` (because `sectionmark` might be renewed in `scrpage2` as well).